# How to move this text down

Tags: html, css

I can't get this text aligned perfectly centered vertically, if I add a break tag its sends it all the way to the bottom of the red container.

[image: **Please See Image:**]

```
<div id="stafftop"><span style="color:white"><strong>Hotel Administrators</strong></div>
<div id="mainmid"> <hr />
<br><br>
```

Comment: It's dangerous to go alone. Take this. http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: use the `line-height` property for `#stafftop`

Comment: [CSS padding](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp) might help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try giving your `DIV` a uniform `height` and `line-height`:

```
#stafftop {
     height: 30px;
     line-height: 30px;
}
```